# hide autocomplete (suggestions ) list when scrolling in antd modal / react

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, modal-dialog, antd, scroller

when I started writing on an input field in a simple form it displays an auto suggestion list of old data (autocomplete), when the (window scroll) it disappear and every thing is working fine.

but when I put the input field in antd modal which includes (other scroller) the suggestion list is still appearing when I scroll up/down.

A solution came to my mind which is adding event listener to antd modal scroller (ant-modal-wrapper) so when it is moved I turned off the auto suggestion feature. but I couldn’t find way to add listener to that scroller cuz it is not (window.scroll).

I tried to use jquery also, like

```
$(".ant-modal-wrapper").on("scroll", function() {      
    console.log("Scrolling");
  });
```

but did not work.

Also I used onScroll property inside modal div but did not work.

this is a screenshot may help to explain this issue in antd modal

[suggestions list before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7cBf.png)

[suggestions list after scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i4hS.png)

any suggestions or better solution to fix my issue would be helpful. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to hide options of Autocomplete inside modal.

- Maintain a state say `optionsOpen` and assign it as a value to `open` prop of [Autocomplete](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/#API)
- Add a eventListener on `scroll` in componentDidMount and update the state to false. This will cause the option to close when user does a scroll.
- Remove eventListener in componentWillUnmount

[Working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-autocomplete-inside-modal-scroll-issue-fix-7vird?file=/index.js:27-3374)

**Code Snippet**

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Modal, Button } from "antd";
import { AutoComplete } from "antd";
const mockVal = (str, repeat = 1) => ({
  value: str.repeat(repeat)
});
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { visible: false, value: "", options: [], optionOpen: false };
  scrolListener = () => {
    if(this.state.optionOpen !== false && this.state.visible)
      this.setState({ optionOpen: false });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrolListener, true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrolListener);
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true
    });
  };

  handleOk = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  handleCancel = e => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  onSearch = searchText => {
    this.setState({
      optionOpen: true,
      options: !searchText
        ? []
        : [mockVal(searchText), mockVal(searchText, 2), mockVal(searchText, 3)]
    });
  };

  onSelect = data => {
    console.log("onSelect", data);
  };

  onChange = data => {
    this.setState({ value: data });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          Open Modal
        </Button>
        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <AutoComplete
            open={this.state.optionOpen}
            options={this.state.options}
            style={{
              width: 200
            }}
            onSelect={this.onSelect}
            onSearch={this.onSearch}
            placeholder="input here"
          />
          <br />
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: I use your code exactly I just make it proper for functional component , but still can't add the listener to the modal scroll ( window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrolListener, true) seems it does not work with modal scroll , I don't know why